# Как добавлять числа в массив от клавиатуры пока пользователь не напишет цифру 0 на Java?

Tags: java, массивы

Как добавлять числа в массив от клавиатуры при этом чтобы он считал повторяющиеся числа

```
package com.company;
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //1 Task
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int elems = 0;
        int kkk = 0;
        int array[] = new int[]{};
        System.out.println("Введите элементы:");
        while (true) {
            elems = in.nextInt();
            if (elems == 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

вывод должен быть таким
2 повторяется 1 раз(а)
4 повторяется 3 раз(а)
5 повторяется 1 раз(а)
7 повторяется 1 раз(а)
11 повторяется 2 раз(а)

Answer (score 0):

Здесь фишка в том, что размер массива - определен изначально. Вы по условию, не знаете сколько чисел будет вводить в массив пользователь. Значит вам нужно каждый раз после считывания цифры, вновь его(массив) инициализировать(Перезаписывать в новый).

А если вы хотите ещё и считать кол-во "совпадений" то это уже двумерный массив.

Всё это есть в гугле, желаю вам успехов!

P.S Это задание поможет вам понять, как работают коллекции по типу ArrayList в дальнейшем.